# Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

i am trying to mage a lollipop app and solved my problems with tabs and style problems, but now i got a error i didn't see before and got no solution by other posts. i don't really know what happens there.

also i am using stack overflow first time to ask a question and i don't really know what all of my code u need for this issue.

thats my
**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/share"
    android:orderInCategory="99"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

see this pastebin for the [error](http://pastebin.com/Csgxt3xp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this doesn't exist:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"/>
```

Are you sure that this exists? You could copy that drawable in your `drawable` folder and use

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"/>
```

instead.